# ".sock" does not exist error; connect() error

Tags: django, nginx, wsgi

I'm trying to set up my Mezzanine/Django project on a virtual Ubuntu 14.04 box on Linode, but get a "502 Bad Gateway error" when trying to navigate to my site in my browser.

I'm following the instructions here: https://linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/deploy-django-applications-using-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04.

I ran `git clone` in `/home/django/`, so everything's in a folder named `FOLDER`.

`/home/django/` has these directories: `Env/` and `FOLDER/`.

This should give some idea of what `FOLDER/` tree looks like:

```
FOLDER
- product_blog
-- product_blog
--- settings.py
--- wsgi.py
-- manage.py
```

In my `settings.py`, I have:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["PUBLIC IP OF MY LINODE UBUNTU INSTANCE HERE"]
```

`wsgi.py` has this:

```
"""
WSGI config for product_blog project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from mezzanine.utils.conf import real_project_name

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",
                      "%s.settings" % real_project_name("product_blog"))

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

`/etc/uwsgi/sites/product_blog.ini` has this:

```
[uwsgi]
project = product_blog
base = /home/django

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 2

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
```

`/etc/init/uwsgi.conf` has this:

```
description "uWSGI"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn

env UWSGI=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi
env LOGTO=/var/log/uwsgi.log

exec $UWSGI --master --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites --die-on-term --uid django --gid www-data --logto $LOGTO
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/product_blog` has this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/django/FOLDER;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/django/FOLDER/product_blog/product_blog.sock;
    }
}
```

When I go to the IP address for the Linode box, I see a 502 Bad Gateway error.

`/var/log/uwsgi.log` has this...

```
*** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 6) ***
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from product_blog.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.17 (64bit) on [Sun Apr 22 17:17:56 2018] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.4 on 22 April 2018 19:53:45
os: Linux-4.15.12-x86_64-linode105 #1 SMP Thu Mar 22 02:13:40 UTC 2018
nodename: ubuntu-linode
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/sites
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
chdir() to /home/django/product_blog
chdir(): No such file or directory [core/uwsgi.c line 2629]
chdir(): No such file or directory [core/uwsgi.c line 1644]
Sun Apr 22 17:17:56 2018 - [emperor] curse the uwsgi instance product_blog.ini (pid: 4238)
Sun Apr 22 17:17:59 2018 - [emperor] removed uwsgi instance product_blog.ini
```

And `/var/log/nginx/error.log` has this (identifying info removed):

```
2018/04/22 17:18:14 [crit] 3953#0: *9 connect() to unix:/home/django/FOLDER/product_blog/product_blog.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 73.49.35.42, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/django/FOLDER/product_blog/product_blog.sock:", host: "ADDRESS TO LINODE BOX"
```

It seems that `product_blog.sock` is supposed to be somewhere in my directory, but it is not there. How do I fix the 502 error so that I can navigate my browser to the Linode box's address and see a working website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket file is supposed to be created by uWSGI. But the uWSGI log is telling you that it can't start up because it can't cd to the directory you have specified in product_blog.ini, `/home/django/product_blog`.

I can't tell if `FOLDER` is a placeholder or not, but in any case you don't seem to have included it in that path. I suppose it should be:

```
chdir = %(base)/FOLDER/%(project)
...
socket = %(base)/FOLDER/%(project)/%(project).sock
```